# Can't install php-mssql on CentOS 5

Tags: centos, yum, php

When I try to run

> yum install php-mssql

I get the following error

```
--> Processing Conflict: mysql conflicts MySQL
--> Processing Conflict: mysql-server conflicts MySQL-server
--> Finished Dependency Resolution mysql-5.0.45-7.el5.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems   --> mysql conflicts with mysql mysql-server-5.0.45-7.el5.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems   --> mysql-server conflicts with mysql-server Error: mysql conflicts with mysql Error: mysql-server conflicts with mysql-server  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

It starts with

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www7.atomicorp.com
 * epel: mirror.fraunhofer.de
```

When I run

> package-cleanup --dupes | grep mysql

```
mysql-server-5.0.90-1.el5.art.x86_64
mysql-server-5.0.45-7.el5.x86_64
mysql-5.0.90-1.el5.art.x86_64
mysql-5.0.45-7.el5.x86_64
```

I am trying to install the mssql package but it looks like there is a problem with mysql? Can I uninstall mysql-server-5.0.45-7.el5.x86_64 and mysql-5.0.45-7.el5.x86_64?

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your have a non-centos version of MySQL installed and it is complaining about that conflict.

```
rpm -qa | grep MySQL
```

See if you have that installed also. along with @Quinn's post

Comment: Thanks Mike, I get two packages trying your command, what do you suggest?

perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-1.fc6   and  
perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5

Answer (score 1):

The message makes it seem like 5.0.90 was pre-installed, and the problem is getting that older version on.  Regardless, you can remove the packages like so:

```
rpm -ev mysql-server-5.0.45-7.el5.x86_64
rpm -ev mysql-5.0.45-7.el5.x86_64
```

You should be able to run the install after that.

Comment: I think that is part of the issue

Comment: I tried yum remove mysql-5.0.45-7.el5.x86_64, it removed both the packages, now I don't have the dependency issue, it is something else, we are getting closer, thanks for your help.

Comment: did you try the yum package-cleanup --problems? What did it return?  Also, it might be useful to edit your main questions with the dvelopments so it is easier to track.

Answer (score 1):

Quinn was helpful, I tried

yum remove mysql-5.0.45-7.el5.x86_64

It removed both the packages. Now when I try

> yum install php-mssql

```
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.5.25-7.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: mysql = 5.5.25-7.el5.art for package: mysql-server
Error: No Package Matching 
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: did you try a yum update before the yum install?

Comment: Excellent, that's all it needed!